# The gridview data in my web application is not corresponding to the selection chosen from the dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am very new to C#. I am trying to create a web application that will allow users to see classes based on a subject they choose from a drop down list. The code I have isn't showing the user the information they chose from the dropdownlist. It shows the same gridview data no matter which option is chosen.

This is the code that will show the web application.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Summer.aspx.cs"Inherits="Summer" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
    <title>Summer 2016</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
     <h1>Summer 2016</h1>
         <h2>Classes offered</h2>
         <h3>Please Choose a Subject</h3>
     </div>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Subjects" DataValueField="Subjects">
         </asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Subject], [Id] FROM [Classes]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
             <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Instrutor" HeaderText="Instrutor" SortExpression="Instrutor" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="CRN" HeaderText="CRN" SortExpression="CRN" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Credits" HeaderText="Credits" SortExpression="Credits" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Day" HeaderText="Day" SortExpression="Day" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="Time" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" SortExpression="Section" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="BeginEnd" HeaderText="BeginEnd" SortExpression="BeginEnd" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="Number" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="SubjectId_Fk" HeaderText="SubjectId_Fk" SortExpression="SubjectId_Fk" />
             </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Instrutor], [CRN], [Credits], [Day], [Time], [Title], [Section], [Location], [BeginEnd], [Number], [SubjectId_Fk] FROM [Classes]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
         <br />
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the code behind for the web application.

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
public partial class Summer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           // DropDownList1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Subject";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            using (SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[@"C:\Users\Keith\Documents\Registration.mdf"].ConnectionString))
            {
             using (SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Classes where Id=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString(), Cn))
            {
            Cn.Open();

                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
                SqlDataReader Dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (Dr.HasRows)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = Dr;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
                Dr.Close();

                Cn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
    public static DataTable GetDataTable(string sqlCommand)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        try
        {
             using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[@"C:\Users\Keith\Documents\Registration.mdf"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, myConnection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(table);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            table = null;
            throw ex;
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you put breakpoints in your code above, are they being hit?

Comment: @CodingYoshi I am not sure how to do that

Comment: if you are using Visual Studio, go to the specific line press F9. You will see a red dot. Then start the site and change the dropdown and it should stop at that dot. If it does not, then that is your issue.

Comment: @CodingYoshi would this line be at the start of the DropDownList function?

Comment: Learn how to do that before you write another line of code. Here is a youtube video which will show you all this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ab4z9u7Q_I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Dropdown element as below,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 

runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 

DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Subjects" 

DataValueField="Subjects" 

onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">

     </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: It is now giving me a NullReferenceException at my connection string